# Does investing money in other currencies help pad losses in case of a stock market crash?

Tags: foreign-exchange, markets, stock-markets

[I was just reading this article](http://www.moneynews.com/MKTNewsIntl/Stock-market-recession-alert/2014/02/10/id/551985/).

Does converting `USD` to say `Euros` help pad oneself against a potential US stock market crash?

While I understand that a US crash would affect the rest of the world and perhaps the Euro would go down, but hypothetically if there were a crash would the `Euro` to `USD` exchange rate go up and thus at some point I could change a balance back to `USD` and not feel as much "financial pain" as I would otherwise?

Comment: That article looks a little fishy

Comment: It could help reduce your loss, but there would likely still be a loss.

Comment: The tradeoff is that now you have `EUR`, and unless you spend a lot of time in Europe, you *will* need to change them back to `USD` if you ever want to spend them.  So now you run the risk that `EUR` will devalue relative to `USD` (regardless of changes in the US stock market).  Just sticking the cash in a bank account in `USD` would be less risky.

Comment: @Karancan - yes, I began to think a bit so also after I did some more research on similar articles (not so much found) and of course the "... rumors of ..." as mentioned in the article not quite hard facts.

Comment: Investing USD in USD would help pad loses in case of a stock market crash.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the equity market in the USA crashed, its very likely equity markets everywhere else would crash. The USA has a high number of the [world's largest businesses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_largest_companies_by_revenue) and there are correlations between equity markets.

So you need to think of equities as a global asset class, not regional.

Your question is then a question about the correlation between equity markets and currency markets.

Here's a guess: If equity markets crashed, you would see a lot of panic selling of stocks denominated in many currencies, but probably the most in USD, due to the large number of the world's largest businesses trading on US stock exchanges. Therefore, when the rest of the world sells US equities they receive cash USD, which they might sell for their local currency. That selling pressure would cause USD to fall. But, when equity markets crash there's a move to safety of the bond markets. The world's largest bond markets are denominated in which currency? Probably USD. So those who receive USD for their equities are going to spend that USD on bonds. In which case there is probably no correlation between equity markets and currency markets at all.

A quick google search shows [this kind of thing](http://www.investopedia.com/ask/answers/06/usdollarcorrelation.asp)